# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: Thread using JNIEnv* from different thread

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

When I try to call the function in the java class, I get the following error.

```
ava_vm_ext.cc:579] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[21,tid=15479,Native,Thread*=0x7d932413a0,peer=0x12f00038,"ImageReader-640x480f23u3m2-15444-0"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[1,tid=15444,Runnable,Thread*=0x7d931f4be0,peer=0x71d8ae98,"main"]
                                                                                                  java_vm_ext.cc:579]     in call to FindClass.
```

Code;

```
void callJavaFun(
        JNIEnv *jniEnv,
        jobject thiz,
        JavaVM *jniGvm,
        jmethodID methodID,
        jclass globalClass,
        cv::Mat &rgb
) {
    jclass clazz = jniEnv->FindClass("com/test/testQ/Yolov8Ncnn");
    jmethodID methodID = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clazz, "test", "()V");
    if (methodID != NULL) {
        jniEnv->CallVoidMethod(thiz, methodID);
    }
}
```

When I run the code in the following line of code I don't have any problem.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_test_testQ_Yolov8Ncnn_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject surface) {
    ...
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You have to use CallBooleanMethod not CallVoidMethod.

Comment: Also the signature ()V is wrong. See this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jni/types.html

Comment: The error could not be clearer: you are using a JNIEnv from a different thread. This is an error. You should use the `AttachCurrentThread` invocation API instead to get a `JNIEnv*`. Also note that non-main threads cannot use `FindClass`, this is a [FAQ](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class)

Answer (score 5):

The error you're encountering typically occurs when you're trying to use a JNIEnv pointer obtained from one thread in another thread. The JNIEnv is specific to the thread it is obtained in and should not be used in a different thread.

In your "callJavaFun" function, you're passing the jniEnv parameter, which is presumably obtained in another thread, to jniEnv->FindClass("com/test/testQ/Yolov8Ncnn") and subsequently trying to use it to find the class and call a method in a different thread. This is not allowed in JNI.

If you need to call JNI functions from another thread, you should obtain a new JNIEnv pointer specifically for that thread using JavaVM functions like AttachCurrentThread and DetachCurrentThread. AttachCurrentThread is used to obtain a JNIEnv pointer for the current thread, perform the JNI operations, and then DetachCurrentThread is used to release the JNIEnv when we're done. This ensures that you're using the JNIEnv in a thread-safe manner. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to correctly call JNI functions in another thread:

```
void callJavaFun(
        JNIEnv *jniEnv,
        jobject thiz,
        JavaVM *jniGvm,
        jmethodID methodID,
        jclass globalClass,
        cv::Mat &rgb
) {
    JNIEnv *threadEnv = nullptr;
    if (jniGvm->AttachCurrentThread(&threadEnv, NULL) == JNI_OK) {
        jclass clazz = threadEnv->FindClass("com/test/testQ/Yolov8Ncnn");
        jmethodID methodID = threadEnv->GetMethodID(clazz, "test", "()V");
        if (methodID != NULL) {
            threadEnv->CallVoidMethod(thiz, methodID);
        }

        jniGvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    }
}
```